# How do I insert statements inside Newtonsoft.JSON codes

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So basically I wanted to do:
json code,
statement,
when statement is true,some other json text
continuation of previous json code

This is currently my code and I'm looking a way to shorten it, any solutions?

```
if (textBox1.Text != "Enter Address")
            {
                if (textBox2.Text != "Enter Address")
                {
                    //1+2+3 OK
                    if (textBox3.Text != "Enter Address")
                    {
                        var item = new Item
                        {
                            version = 1,
                            schema_version = 2,
                            id = textBox14.Text,
                            title = textBox7.Text,
                            title_localized = textBox18.Text,
                            artist = textBox6.Text,
                            artist_localized = textBox8.Text,
                            artist_source = textBox9.Text,
                            illustrator = textBox10.Text,
                            illustrator_source = textBox11.Text,
                            charter = textBox13.Text,
                            music = new ItemMusic                                {
                                path = textBox4.Text
                            },
                            music_preview = new ItemMusicPreview
                            {
                                path = textBox5.Text
                            },
                            background = new ItemBackground
                            {
                                path = open3.SafeFileName
                            },
                            charts = new List<ItemChart>
{
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "easy",
        name = textBox15.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value),
        path = textBox1.Text
    },
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "hard",
        name = textBox16.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value),
        path = textBox2.Text
    },
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "extreme",
        name = textBox17.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown3.Value),
        path = textBox3.Text
    }
}
                        };

                        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                            {
                                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                            }
                        };
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, settings);
                        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\") == false)
                        {
                            // Make a path
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\");
                        }
                        if (File.Exists($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\") == false)
                        {
                            // Make a path
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\");
                        }
                        File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\level.json", json, new UTF8Encoding(false));
                    }
                    //1+2 (3) OK
                    else
                    {
                        var item = new Item
                        {
                            version = 1,
                            schema_version = 2,
                            id = textBox14.Text,
                            title = textBox7.Text,
                            title_localized = textBox18.Text,
                            artist = textBox6.Text,
                            artist_localized = textBox8.Text,
                            artist_source = textBox9.Text,
                            illustrator = textBox10.Text,
                            illustrator_source = textBox11.Text,
                            charter = textBox13.Text,
                            music = new ItemMusic
                            {
                                path = textBox4.Text
                            },
                            music_preview = new ItemMusicPreview
                            {
                                path = textBox5.Text
                            },
                            background = new ItemBackground
                            {
                                path = open3.SafeFileName
                            },
                            charts = new List<ItemChart>
{
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "easy",
        name = textBox15.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value),
        path = textBox1.Text
    },
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "hard",
        name = textBox16.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value),
        path = textBox2.Text
    }
}
                        };

                        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                            {
                                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                            }
                        };
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, settings);
                        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\") == false)
                        {
                            // Make a path
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\");
                        }
                        if (File.Exists($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\") == false)
                        {
                            // Make a path
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\");
                        }
                        File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\level.json", json, new UTF8Encoding(false));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    //1+3 (2) OK
                    if (textBox3.Text != "Enter Address")
                    {
                        var item = new Item
                        {
                            version = 1,
                            schema_version = 2,
                            id = textBox14.Text,
                            title = textBox7.Text,
                            title_localized = textBox18.Text,
                            artist = textBox6.Text,
                            artist_localized = textBox8.Text,
                            artist_source = textBox9.Text,
                            illustrator = textBox10.Text,
                            illustrator_source = textBox11.Text,
                            charter = textBox13.Text,
                            music = new ItemMusic
                            {
                                path = textBox4.Text
                            },
                            music_preview = new ItemMusicPreview
                            {
                                path = textBox5.Text
                            },
                            background = new ItemBackground
                            {
                                path = open3.SafeFileName
                            },
                            charts = new List<ItemChart>
{
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "easy",
        name = textBox15.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value),
        path = textBox1.Text
    },
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "extreme",
        name = textBox17.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown3.Value),
        path = textBox3.Text
    }
}
                        };

                        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                            {
                                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                            }
                        };
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, settings);
                        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\") == false)
                        {
                            // Make a path
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\");
                        }
                        if (File.Exists($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\") == false)
                        {
                            // Make a path
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\");
                        }
                        File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\level.json", json, new UTF8Encoding(false));
                    }
                    //1 (2)(3) OK
                    else
                    {
                        var item = new Item
                        {
                            version = 1,
                            schema_version = 2,
                            id = textBox14.Text,
                            title = textBox7.Text,
                            title_localized = textBox18.Text,
                            artist = textBox6.Text,
                            artist_localized = textBox8.Text,
                            artist_source = textBox9.Text,
                            illustrator = textBox10.Text,
                            illustrator_source = textBox11.Text,
                            charter = textBox13.Text,
                            music = new ItemMusic
                            {
                                path = textBox4.Text
                            },
                            music_preview = new ItemMusicPreview
                            {
                                path = textBox5.Text
                            },
                            background = new ItemBackground
                            {
                                path = open3.SafeFileName
                            },
                            charts = new List<ItemChart>
{
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "easy",
        name = textBox15.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value),
        path = textBox1.Text
    }
}
                        };

                        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                        {
                            ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                            {
                                NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                            }
                        };
                        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, settings);
                        if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\") == false)
                        {
                            // Make a path
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\");
                        }
                        if (File.Exists($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\") == false)
                        {
                            // Make a path
                            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\");
                        }
                        File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\level.json", json, new UTF8Encoding(false));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            if (textBox2.Text != "Enter Address")
            {
                //2+3 (1) OK
                if (textBox3.Text != "Enter Address")
                {
                    var item = new Item
                    {
                        version = 1,
                        schema_version = 2,
                        id = textBox14.Text,
                        title = textBox7.Text,
                        title_localized = textBox18.Text,
                        artist = textBox6.Text,
                        artist_localized = textBox8.Text,
                        artist_source = textBox9.Text,
                        illustrator = textBox10.Text,
                        illustrator_source = textBox11.Text,
                        charter = textBox13.Text,
                        music = new ItemMusic
                        {
                            path = textBox4.Text
                        },
                        music_preview = new ItemMusicPreview
                        {
                            path = textBox5.Text
                        },
                        background = new ItemBackground
                        {
                            path = open3.SafeFileName
                        },
                        charts = new List<ItemChart>
{
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "hard",
        name = textBox16.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value),
        path = textBox2.Text
    },
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "extreme",
        name = textBox17.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown3.Value),
        path = textBox3.Text
    }
}
                    };

                    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                        {
                            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                        }
                    };
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, settings);
                    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\") == false)
                    {
                        // Make a path
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\");
                    }
                    if (File.Exists($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\") == false)
                    {
                        // Make a path
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\");
                    }
                    File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\level.json", json, new UTF8Encoding(false));
                }
                //2 (1)(3)
                else
                {
                    var item = new Item
                    {
                        version = 1,
                        schema_version = 2,
                        id = textBox14.Text,
                        title = textBox7.Text,
                        title_localized = textBox18.Text,
                        artist = textBox6.Text,
                        artist_localized = textBox8.Text,
                        artist_source = textBox9.Text,
                        illustrator = textBox10.Text,
                        illustrator_source = textBox11.Text,
                        charter = textBox13.Text,
                        music = new ItemMusic
                        {
                            path = textBox4.Text
                        },
                        music_preview = new ItemMusicPreview
                        {
                            path = textBox5.Text
                        },
                        background = new ItemBackground
                        {
                            path = open3.SafeFileName
                        },
                        charts = new List<ItemChart>
{
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "hard",
        name = textBox16.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value),
        path = textBox2.Text
    }
}
                    };

                    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                    {
                        ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                        {
                            NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                        }
                    };
                    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, settings);
                    if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\") == false)
                    {
                        // Make a path
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\");
                    }
                    if (File.Exists($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\") == false)
                    {
                        // Make a path
                        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\");
                    }
                    File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\level.json", json, new UTF8Encoding(false));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                var item = new Item
                {
                    version = 1,
                    schema_version = 2,
                    id = textBox14.Text,
                    title = textBox7.Text,
                    title_localized = textBox18.Text,
                    artist = textBox6.Text,
                    artist_localized = textBox8.Text,
                    artist_source = textBox9.Text,
                    illustrator = textBox10.Text,
                    illustrator_source = textBox11.Text,
                    charter = textBox13.Text,
                    music = new ItemMusic
                    {
                        path = textBox4.Text
                    },
                    music_preview = new ItemMusicPreview
                    {
                        path = textBox5.Text
                    },
                    background = new ItemBackground
                    {
                        path = open3.SafeFileName
                    },
                    charts = new List<ItemChart>
{
    new ItemChart
    {
        type = "extreme",
        name = textBox17.Text,
        difficulty = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown3.Value),
        path = textBox3.Text
    },
}
                };

                var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
                    {
                        NamingStrategy = new SnakeCaseNamingStrategy()
                    }
                };
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, settings);
                if (File.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\") == false)
                {
                    // Make a path
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\");
                }
                if (File.Exists($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\") == false)
                {
                    // Make a path
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\");
                }
                File.WriteAllText($@"C:\Users\Public\Desktop\level files\{textBox14.Text}\level.json", json, new UTF8Encoding(false));
            }
```

I was going to add "storyboard = open9.FileName" to "new ItemChart"s but *not* add the storyboard line when the file address is not imported.